# How to create a calculated field in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a Firebase application and I want to store the subscription details of users in it. I'm planning to store the start_date, end_date, and number_of_days_left for the subscription. I want to calculate number_of_days_left based on the difference between end_date and current_date. The number_of_days_left should update every day in the Firebase. What's the best possible way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired task you can use [Scheduled Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). This function creates a **Pub/Sub** topic and uses **Cloud Scheduler** to trigger events on that topic which ensures that the function runs on the desired schedule.

To store `start_date`, `end_date` and `number_of_days_left` of the subscription you can use **Cloud Firestore**.

First you can create a `users` collection in Firestore. And add a unique document when a user subscribes to the application. In the document you can store the `start_date`,  `end_date` with the field of type `timestamp` and `number_of_days_left` with type `number`.

The Firestore database structure will look like the following -

```
users------>
    user1------>
        start_date
        end_date
        number_of_days_left
    user2----->
        start_date
        end_date
        number_of_days_left
    user3----->
        start_date
        end_date
        number_of_days_left
```

Now you can implement the scheduled Firebase Function and update the `number_of_days_left` field everyday. The scheduled Firebase Function uses Unix Crontab. You can find more about Unix Crontab syntax [here](https://crontab.guru/). The following scheduled Firebase Function, which is in **NodeJS**, runs at `00:00` everyday and updates the `number_of_days_left` field for every user inside the `users` collection.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();
const db=admin.firestore();
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *")
   .timeZone("Asia/Kolkata")
   // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
   .onRun(async (context) => {
     const docRef = await db.collection("users").get();
     docRef.forEach((doc)=>{
       const data=doc.data();
       const difference=Math.
           floor((data.end_date-admin.firestore.Timestamp.now())/(24*60*60));
       doc.ref.update({"number_of_days_left": difference});
     });
   });
```

In the Function code you can specify any valid `timezone` of your choice which is listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, I recommend you to use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/):

> Cloud Scheduler is a fully managed enterprise-grade cron job scheduler.

So you can create a cron to update that difference daily. In that way, you'll always have a field that will contain the exact number of days left.